# Is it possible to create transparent canvas

Tags: canvas, processing.js

I am developing a paint brush application in javascript using processing.js
It is using a canvas object. I want to keep an image at the background of the canvas. Draw something in the foreground. And while saving i need to get only foreground data.

For that we need to make canvas object transparent so that background image is visible.

I don't see any option to make the canvas transparent. How do I do that?

Comment: The correct answer for this was Jared's. Why? Because the original poster said he needed it to be done with *ProcessingJS*, which renders all canvas elements with gray background as *default*. He wants to override this default behavior.

Answer (score 13):

Even better, at the top of your pjs just put:

```
/* @pjs transparent=true; */
```

... and then in your draw loop:

```
background(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

voila!

Comment: Correct answer when using *ProcessingJS*. It also solved my problems.

Answer (score 6):

`<canvas>` is transparent by default.

I've made a proof of concept that can be found here:

http://irae.pro.br/lab/canvas_pie_countdown/

Tested against IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox 2, Firefox 3, Chrome and iPhone.

Comment: That works when using other canvas libraries/API's. Note that the original poster said he needed it to be done with *ProcessingJS*, which renders all canvas elements with gray background as *default*. He wants to override this default behavior. The answer by Jared is actually the correct one.

Comment: No problem. I also make my frequent mistakes. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
context.clearRect(0,0,width, height)
```

is all you need =)

Keep in mind that you can use CSS styling on the canvas object.

```
canvas.style.position = "absolute";  
canvas.style.left = the x position of the div you're going over +"px";  
canvas.style.top = the y position of the div you're going over + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

why not put the image in the canvas and make your strokes and fills transparent?